# How to install boot repair tool in ubuntu 14.04 live?

Tags: 14.04

I am not able to install boot repair tool via terminal. I have tried many commands.. Not working...

Answer (score 4):

This is all covered in the [`boot-repair` documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair).

The first step is getting an internet connection. An ethernet connection will probably be automatic but you'll probably need to toy around with network manager to get a WiFi connection up.

Then just open a terminal and run:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo sed 's/trusty/saucy/g' -i /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yannubuntu-boot-repair-trusty.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair
sudo boot-repair &
```

If `add-apt-repository` isn't working, there's almost certainly something wrong with your network connection. Stop there and either fix it or just download [an ISO that has `boot-repair` on the image.](http://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair-cd/home/Home/)

---

The repository mentioned above currently only contains versions for 12.04, 12.10, 13.04 and 13.10. The second command should make it available for 14.04. If you're using an older version than these (or you've download a 14.10+ pre-release ISO), you can:

- Alter the `sed` command depending on your release,

  ```
  . /etc/lsb-release
  sed "s/$DISTRIB_CODENAME/saucy/ -i /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yannubuntu-boot-repair-$DISTRIB_CODENAME.list
  ```
- Download an ISO that is supported,
- Just download an ISO that includes it (as above), or
- Manually download the deb from the [package list](https://launchpad.net/~yannubuntu/+archive/boot-repair/+packages) and install that.

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

i have tried all of these mentioned in the article... It starts very fine. But at last in terminal shows a 404 error... Thats why there is no boot repair tool. I am using mobile broadband connection...

Comment: Should I have to try Boot repair disk???? If I have to do this, which version should I choose??? I'm using 32bit of ubuntu 14.04

Comment: I'd go for the same architecture as my install but it shouldn't make much difference.

Comment: Finally, what I have  to do now??? I'm confused !! Go for rescue cd??

Answer (score 0):

To install Boot-Repair in Ubuntu

- connect to the Internet
- open a new Terminal, then type the following commands (press Enter after each line):

  ```
  sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
  sudo apt-get update
  sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
  ```